# Creating an instance of a jQuery Mobile Page

Tags: oop, jquery-mobile, instantiation

I'd like be able to create instances of jQuery mobile pages using an existing jQuery Mobile page as a template. Can anyone point me in the right directing on this. Does anything exist along the lines of:

```
var pageInstance = new $mobile.createPage();
```

Answer (score 0):

If you sure your page is currently loaded into the DOM.Try with this,

```
var page = $('#PageId');
```